# JDBC inactivity timeout (MS SQL Database)

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, connection, timeout

On my setup with a JDBC driver that connects to a Microsoft SQL Server 2019 database, I experience the following "connection broken" error if there is more than ~12h inactivity.
The error is:

> The connection is broken and recovery is not possible. The connection is marked by the client driver as unrecoverable. No attempt was made to restore the connection.

How to extend that inactivity timeout? Is it a setting of the MSSQL server?

Trying to find an appropriate setting for the JDBC connection. I could not find any.

Comment: I would ask, why do you need a connection open for 12+ hours.

Comment: The inactive TCP connection is likely being terminated by a network appliance (firewall). The same symptoms may occur due a break in network connectivity. Connection poolers may handle these more gracefully than a persistent connection.

Comment: Thanks @DanGuzman for the explanation. Larnu the reason is an application, that uses queries the db and is sometimes inactive for several hours.